# How to add the multiple payment profiles while adding the single customer?

Tags: authorize.net

Using sandbox key and transaction id when I'm creating the user using json flavour. This api will response me the customerProfileId and customerPaymentProfileIdList in the list there is one id. Can we create it multiples? if yes, Then what is the json string I have to send to generate multiple customerPaymentProfileIds. If no, Then please expalin why I'm not sending the array to the api. Or how to create the multiple payment profiles using authrization.net.

Now I'm sending this json:-

```
{
  "createCustomerProfileRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
        "name": "name",
        "transactionKey": "transaction_key"
    },
    "profile": {
        "merchantCustomerId": "This is a+fdstring",
        "description": "This is a description.",
        "email": "RuldaRam@gmail.com",
        "paymentProfiles": {
            "customerType": "individual",
            "billTo":{
                "firstName":"Puneet",
                "lastName":"Jindal",
                "address":"Mohali",
                "city":"Banglore",
                "state":"Delhi",
                "zip":"10001"
            },
            "payment": {
                "creditCard": {
                    "cardNumber": "4111111111111111",
                    "expirationDate": "2020-12",
                    "cardCode":"123"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "validationMode": "testMode"
  }
}
```

Developer [link](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-create-customer-profile)

I also tried to do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953698/how-to-solve-the-error-of-the-element-createcustomerprofilerequest-in-namespac)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the error of The element 'createCustomerProfileRequest' in namespace while adding the customer mutiple payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953698/how-to-solve-the-error-of-the-element-createcustomerprofilerequest-in-namespac)

Comment: Please delete this question as you essentially duplicated it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953698/how-to-solve-the-error-of-the-element-createcustomerprofilerequest-in-namespac).